# Why Gap Shows when rows are collapsed in a table?

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

In the jsfiddle below I have a gap between the 2nd and 3rd rows, I guess it is due to the CSS but I am not sure why it is there and how to get rid of it.

If I move the 2nd row to be the last, the gap goes away, but I want to keep the current order of rows.

Tested on Windows-10, Google Chrome Browser.

[JsFiddle with problem code](https://jsfiddle.net/ekareem/evwxu93j/3/)

CSS:

```css
.collapse-row.collapsed+tr {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
    <th>6</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion" class="clickable collapse-row collapsed">
      <td>r1</td>
      <td>Some more stuff</td>
      <td>And some more</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">
        <div id="accordion" class="collapse">Hidden by default 1</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion2" class="clickable">
      <td>r2</td>
      <td>Some more stuff</td>
      <td>And some more</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">
        <div id="accordion2" class="collapse">Hidden by default 2</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Problem is between the above and below rows -->
    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion15" class="clickable collapse-row collapsed">
      <td>r3-Design Data Model</td>
      <td>Feb-22-2019</td>
      <td>Mar-01-2019</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>+</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">
        <div id="accordion15" class="collapse">Hidden by default 3 </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why you have added blank <tr> and <td>? 
<tr>
    <td colspan="6">
        <div id="accordion2" class="collapse">Hidden by default 2</div>
     </td>
 </tr>

Comment: Click on the row above..

Comment: your selector `.collapse-row.collapsed` is matching nothing here . where is the attribute `class="collapse-row collapsed "` in your html ?

Comment: @JoykalInfotech, not sure what you mean. I have this structure <tr><td><div></div></tr> with no empty entries.

Comment: @NoChance please check the answer. I have explained the issue

Comment: Why 2nd row has no the same `class`es as the 1st and 3rd?

Comment: Just add `collapse-row` and `collapsed` classes to that particular row. That way your css will work. You use that css but only for some rows.

Comment: @MoshFeu, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually **2nd row** not contain `collapse-row` and `collapsed` class and you apply CSS if both `collapse-row` and `collapsed` are available.

```
.collapse-row.collapsed + tr {
  display: none;
}
```

Replace your CSS with the below CSS, will resolve your issue. Thanks

```
.clickable + tr {
  display: none;
}
```

Another option you just add `collapse-row collapsed` classes in **2nd row**

```
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion2" class="clickable collapse-row collapsed">
   <td>r2</td>
   <td>Some more stuff</td>
   <td>And some more</td>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>6</td> 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add `collapsed` `collapse-row` class in your second row `<tr>` same as other two . Default `display: none;` CSS is not applying to that  that's why it taking space.

Comment: Adding a `collapsed` class will not resolve the issue. because the css apply if both `collapse-row collapsed` available on **tr**. Thanks

Comment: Why did your answer get downvoted ? It fixes the issue.

Comment: Because this is not a good complete answer. Besides the explanation it should include also a code snippet that demonstrates that explanation

Comment: Thank you your answer is correct. I did not down-vote. I accepted the other answer just because it came first (I can only accept 1 answer - Sorry about that).